# Can I .set_index() lazily ( or to be executed concurrently ), on Dask Dataframes?

Tags: python, dataframe, concurrency, dask, dask-distributed

> tl;dr:
>  Is it possible to **`.set_index()`** method on several Dask Dataframes <strike>in parallel</strike> concurrently? Alternatively, is it possible to `.set_index()` lazily on several Dask Dataframes which, consequently, would lead to the indexes being set <strike>in parallel</strike> concurrently?

Here is the scenario:

- I have several time series
- Each time series is stored is several **`.csv`** files. Each file contains data related to a specific day. Also, files are scattered amongst different folders (each folder is contains data for one month)
- Each time series has different sampling rates
- All time series have the same columns. All have a column which contains `DateTime`, amongst others.
- Data is too large to be processed in memory. That's why I am using Dask.
- I want to merge all the time series into a single DataFrame, aligned by `DateTime`. For this, I need to first `resample()` each and all time series to a common sampling rate. And then `.join()` all time series.
- `.resample()` can only be applied on index. Hence, before resampling I need to `.set_index()` on the DateTime column on each time series.
- When I ask `.set_index()` method on one time series, computation starts immediately. Which leads to my code being blocked and waiting. At this moment, if I check my machine resources usage, I can see that many cores are being used but the usage does not go above ~15%. Which makes me think that, ideally, I could have the `.set_index()` method being applied to more than one time series at the same time.

After reaching the above situation, I've tried some not elegant solutions to parallelize application of `.set_index()` method on several time series (e.g. create a **`multiprocessing.Pool`** ), which were not successful. Before giving more details on those, is there a clean way on how to solve the situation above? Was the above scenario thought at some point when implementing Dask?

Alternatively, is it possible to `.set_index()` lazily? If `.set_index()` method could be applied lazily, I would create a full computation graph with the steps described above and in the end ,everything would be computed <strike>in parallel</strike> concurrently (I think).

Answer (score 1):

Dask.dataframe needs to know the min and max values of all of the partitions of the dataframe in order to sensibly do datetime operations in parallel.  By default it will read the data once in order to find good partitions.  If the data is not sorted it will then do a shuffle (perhaps very expensive) to sort

In your case it sounds like your data is already sorted and that you might be able to provide these explicitly.  You should look at the last example of the [`dd.DataFrame.set_index` docstring](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.set_index)

```
    A common case is when we have a datetime column that we know to be
    sorted and is cleanly divided by day.  We can set this index for free
    by specifying both that the column is pre-sorted and the particular
    divisions along which is is separated

    >>> import pandas as pd
    >>> divisions = pd.date_range('2000', '2010', freq='1D')
    >>> df2 = df.set_index('timestamp', sorted=True, divisions=divisions)  # doctest: +SKIP
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply @MRocklin. I forgot to say that. I've tried it with `sorted=True` but it was still very slow (I'm talking about data from about 5 years in many cases with a sampling rate less then a second). I struggled with getting `divisions=divisions` working even when the `len()` matched the number of partitions. But I still didn't have enough time to investigate that issue further. But, summarizing, from your comment, you say I cannot easily `set_index()` on 2 Dataframes in parallel? Even if they are not related at all to each other?

Comment: If your data is sorted and you know the divisions then you can easily call set_index.  You might want to learn more about divisions: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-design.html#partitions